# Xamarin Visual Studio 2017 Previewer doesn't work

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Xamarin Visual Studio 2017 Previewer doesn't work, Just shows me XFPageRendererView. I tried any ways, but still, isn't work

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install Java JDK x64，change the path.
2. If it still does not work，you need to install `BuildTools_Full.exe`, then install `Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.4.0.34.msi`, then is's ok

[image: installer image.]

The download urls: 
http://xamarin.azureedge.net/XamarinforVisualStudio/Windows/Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.4.0.34.msi

and

http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/E/D/EEDF18A8-4AED-4CE0-BEBE-70A83094FC5A/BuildTools_Full.exe

Comment: Thanks, After last update the VisualStudio previewer is working now